# ListView lags when i scroll itemlist

Tags: delphi, listview

I have a problem. When using itemlist in `ListView` with 500 items it doesn't lag, but when it contains more than 1000 items, it lags when scrolling through the item list.

Here is what I started with:

```
procedure thread.ListViewAdd;
begin
  Item:=Form1.ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.SubItems.Add('2 column');
  Item.SubItems.Add('3 column');
  Item.SubItems.Add('4 column');
  Item.SubItems.Add('5 column');
end;
```

Then I synchronized this procedure in `thread.Execute` like this:

```
procedure thread.ListViewAdd;
begin
  ListView.Items.BeginUpdate;
try
  Item:=Form1.ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.SubItems.Add('2 column');
  Item.SubItems.Add('3 column');
  Item.SubItems.Add('4 column');
  Item.SubItems.Add('5 column');
finally
  ListView.Items.EndUpdate; 

end;
```

---

Already solved the problem. The problem was here:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  i:integer;
begin

    for i:=0 to Form1.ListView1.Items.Count-1 do
    begin
      Form1.ListView1.Items[i].Caption:=IntToStr(i+1);
    end;

end;
```

This code was updating items for all the time, so it was lagging

Comment: Just a plain vanilla list view with 1000 items? What do you mean by lag?

Comment: when i scroll ListView it lags when it contains more then 1000 items, i can't scroll normally, it's scrolling much logner, longer drawing items and i can see how slowly it draw items...

Comment: in VirtualListView demo i saw using OwnerData:=True then it don't lags, but i don't know how to use it correctly..

Comment: Well, you have your answer it seems. Use virtual.

Comment: You've got the demo. That shows you how.

Comment: yes, but i can't understand

Comment: Keep trying. You'll get there.

Comment: There is no problem with 10000 items in an ordinary TListView. Are you still filling the listview from the thread? Every update (adding, deleting, update) of items will cause some work. Instead of feeding the list with single items in a short interval you should cache them and update the list when you have more than 50 items and/or more then 1000ms since last update. There is no need to populate the items 1ms after they occured

Comment: When updating the listview you should use `Listview.Items.BeginUpdate; try ... finally ListView.Items.EndUpdate; end;`. Now it doesn't matter if you are changing 1 or 1000 itmes

Comment: Can you please respond to @Sir Rufo's comments. You confirmed that you had a problem with a plain vanilla list view with just 1000 items. Sir Rufo says otherwise. It looks to me as though the question is still ill formed. Please provide SSCCE so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: There is not much benefit with BeginUpdate if you just change/add one item. Reduce the change frequency and change a bunch of items in one go

Comment: Your edit doesn't really help. Instead of describing. Show code. Show a complete program.

Comment: RE (edit): You are probably aware of the fact that no one other than you would be able to locate that problem. Your question was basically a waste of everyone's time whomever happened to read and think over it.

Comment: Definitely DO NOT update items in an OnDraw event handler, let alon in a loop that iterates through all of the items while drawing.  Drawing should only use the current values of the specific `Item` being requested by the event. Assignment is not drawing. If you want to make item data updates dynamically, consider switching to a *virtual* ListView (set `OwnerData` to True) and provide the desired data values in the ListView's `OnData` event.

Comment: Yes, a big waste of time because you were too lazy to provide SSCCE. You decided to save your own time by not making SSCCE and waste ours instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use a data class and a second thread for UI notification.

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Classes,
  System.SyncObjs;

type
  TNotifyItems<T> = procedure( Sender : TObject; AItems : TArray<T> ) of object;

  TNotificationThread<T : class> = class( TThread )
  private
    // Synchroobjects
    FCS : TCriticalSection;
    FEvent : TEvent;
    // Cache
    FItems : TObjectList<T>;
    // Event
    FOnNotify : TNotifyItems<T>;
    // Getter/Setter
    function GetOnNotify : TNotifyItems<T>;
    procedure SetOnNotify( const Value : TNotifyItems<T> );
    // Notification
    procedure DoNotifyItems;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure EnqueueItem( AItem : T );
    // Event
    property OnNotify : TNotifyItems<T> read GetOnNotify write SetOnNotify;
  end;

implementation

procedure TNotificationThread<T>.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      // waiting for 1000ms before next notify
      if FEvent.WaitFor( 1000 ) = wrTimeOut
      then
        Synchronize( DoNotifyItems );
    end;
end;

procedure TNotificationThread<T>.DoNotifyItems;
var
  LItems : TList<T>;
  LOnNotify : TNotifyItems<T>;
begin
  LItems := TObjectList<T>.Create( true );
  try
    FCS.Enter;
    try
      // Get the Items and the event
      FItems.OwnsObjects := False;
      try
        LItems.AddRange( FItems );
        FItems.Clear;
      finally
        FItems.OwnsObjects := true;
      end;
      LOnNotify := FOnNotify;
    finally
      FCS.Leave;
    end;

    if Assigned( LOnNotify ) and ( LItems.Count > 0 )
    then
      LOnNotify( Self, LItems.ToArray );
  finally
    LItems.Free;
  end;
end;

constructor TNotificationThread<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited Create( False );
  FCS := TCriticalSection.Create;
  FEvent := TEvent.Create( nil, False, False, '' );
  FItems := TObjectList<T>.Create;
end;

destructor TNotificationThread<T>.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  FItems.Free;
  FEvent.Free;
  FCS.Free;
end;

procedure TNotificationThread<T>.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited;
  FEvent.SetEvent;
end;

function TNotificationThread<T>.GetOnNotify : TNotifyItems<T>;
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  try
    Result := FOnNotify;
  finally
    FCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TNotificationThread<T>.SetOnNotify( const Value : TNotifyItems<T> );
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  try
    FOnNotify := Value;
  finally
    FCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TNotificationThread<T>.EnqueueItem( AItem : T );
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  try
    FItems.Add( AItem );
  finally
    FCS.Leave;
  end;
end;
```

Now feed the NotificationThread from the working thread with data and go on working.

```
procedure TWorkingThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    // do some work
    ...
    // Notify progress, thats all here
    FDataItemNotifier.EnqueueItem( TDataItem.Create( 'Caption', '2 column', '3 column' ) );
  end;
end;
```

Your form now needs an event handler for that notification event

```
procedure TMyForm.DataItemNotification( Sender : TObject; AItems : TArray<TDataItem> );
var
  LItem : TDataItem;
  LListItem : TListItem;
begin
  // now updating the ListView with a bunch of data
  ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for LItem in AItems do
    begin
      LListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
      LListItem.Caption := LItem.Data1Str;
      LListItem.SubItems.Add( LItem.Data2Str );
      LListItem.SubItems.Add( LItem.Data3Str );
    end;
  finally
    ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Sir Rufo, thank you for your answer, it will be good example for people which have the same problem, i had already solved the problem, the problem was in other part of code